# Dropna in pysaprk gives 0 results

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe in spark which has missing values.
I am trying to delete the columns which have more than 50% missing values
See below code:

```
frac =  fil_data.count() * .50
print(frac)
t_data = fil_data.dropna(thresh=390951)
print(t_data.count())
```

The print count gives me 0
why is this happening?
How can we resolve this

I researched a bit before posting, everyone uses the plain simple dropna(how = any or all) instead of threshold

Answer (score 0):

Note that dropna will always drop rows, not columns.
For the correct use of the thresh option see the docs:
`thresh – int, default None If specified, drop rows that have less than thresh non-null values. This overwrites the how parameter.`
So you drop all rows having less than 390951 non-null values, which is probably all since you don't have 400k cols I assume